# How to wrap a crumpled paper over a surface?

Tags: graphics, mesh, generative-art

My initial question was about the making of a crumpled paper. After reading [this article](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/Fall16/Readings/Blinn78.pdf) suggested by J.M. and little more browsing (kind of random walk you do on a Saturday) I thought about expanding the question a little bit.

Q1. How can I make a crumpled paper?

Q2. How to wrap it on a smooth surface?

For example, first I want to create a surface like (Fig.3a of [this page](https://earth.stanford.edu/research/geomech/Software/dynel/examples/example1.html))
[image]

and then I want to wrap it on a smooth surface, say on the northern hemisphere.

I tried to start from a `DelaunayMesh` using the approach given in [Visualize Mesh Properties](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/data-and-mesh-regions/visualize-mesh-properties.html).

```
pts = Join[Tuples[{0, 1}, 2], RandomReal[1, {50, 2}]];
mesh2d = DelaunayMesh[pts];
{minArea, maxArea} = {Min[#], Max[#]} &@ PropertyValue[{mesh2d, 2}, MeshCellMeasure];

HighlightMesh[mesh2d, {Style[1, Opacity[0]], 
  Style @@@ ({{2, #},  GrayLevel[ Rescale[PropertyValue[{mesh2d, {2, #}}, 
  MeshCellMeasure], {minArea, maxArea}]]} & /@ Range[MeshCellCount[mesh2d, 2]])}]
```

which looks like a 2D projection of the wrinkly surface. Then probably a small random z value can be added at each vertex to create the crumpled sheet. And finally, it can be put on the top of a hemisphere.

An alternative way could be using `ListPlot3D` with `InterpolationOrder -> 1`. Using the same set of points

```
ListPlot3D[pts /. {x_, y_} :> {x, y, RandomReal[0.1]}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .2},
InterpolationOrder -> 1, ColorFunction ->GrayLevel, Mesh -> All, PlotRange -> {-0.05, 0.15}]
```

[image]

Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/Fall16/Readings/Blinn78.pdf)?

Comment: Thanks @J.M. for the paper. I was thinking about moving to 3D later - looks like this approach can be applied to any surface (I am not claiming that I can do it now). I think I am going to end up with a lot crumpled paper in real life.

Comment: Can you be more specific about "better"?

Comment: @SimonWoods, sorry for that. I modified my question.

Comment: Assuming paper is inextensible, a crumpled sheet of paper is a developable surface, so its Gaussian curvature should be zero everywhere. Assigning a random $z$ value to each vertex won't give you that. I'm not sure there's a simple process by which you can generate a random developable surface though.

Comment: You should google after and peruse some papers of Tomohiro Tachi regarding crumpling. Putting truly  isometric crumpling on non-developable surfaces is a very complex task.

Comment: Thanks, Rahul and @YvesKlett for the references. First I thought it would be fun to make some graphics; now it turned out to be more fun with all the math inside :)